# Add an anchor to the current controller

Tags: cakephp, controller, anchor, cakephp-1.3

I have an action in a controller that accepts a form and usually moves on to another action.

It sometimes reloads itself though and in that case, I want it to add an anchor to that reload so the page scrolls down to the unfinished part of form.  Something like this:

`http://example.com/registrations/add#scroll-down-to-here`

I've tried using

`$this->redirect(array('#'=>'scroll-down-to-here')`

but that loses all the form information and I get an empty form.

What am I missing?  (Thanks much!)

Comment: `redirect` always generates a GET request, not a POST, so that's not a solution that's going to work. I haven't tried this, but I wonder if including the anchor in the URL that your form is posting to in the first place might work?

Comment: Unfortunately the page needs to load without the anchor first and then if it reloads, then it needs the anchor.

Comment: You will need to handle this in Javascript.

Comment: Do this using Javascript  using query param.

Comment: "Unfortunately the page needs to load without the anchor first and then if it reloads, then it needs the anchor." Right. You load the page without the anchor, but the target of the form in the page could include the anchor. Then, if it needs to re-render instead of redirecting, it should scroll as required.